# Excel: Vlookup Errors

Tags: microsoft-excel

Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here analyzing Public Data set:  Using Vlookup to pull data from sheet "Public" and populate a new column "congrDist" in sheet "CDE Data"

The only result I can get is the column header in "Public",  or in the example below #N/A.  Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEZrV.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8J6x.png)

Comment: Your table array is wrong. It should be something like 'A1:F69' this would give you a table starting with 'A1' in the top left corner and ending with 'F69' in the bottom right. Your lookup value would need to be in cells 'A1' to 'A69'.
Also, are you sure your 'col_index' is correct, 49 gives you the result in column 'AW'